# How how do I create multiple genericVariables in Job DSL script when using the generic-webhook-trigger plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I found a good example [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger) and I used this code to add additional generic variable, but I just don't know how to change the syntax.

```
pipelineJob('Generic Job Example') {
 parameters {
  stringParam('VARIABLE_FROM_POST', '')
 }

 triggers {
  genericTrigger {
   genericVariables {
    genericVariable {
     key("VARIABLE_FROM_POST")
     value("\$.something")
     expressionType("JSONPath") //Optional, defaults to JSONPath
     regexpFilter("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
     defaultValue("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
    }
   }
   genericRequestVariables {
    genericRequestVariable {
     key("requestParameterName")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
   }
   genericHeaderVariables {
    genericHeaderVariable {
     key("requestHeaderName")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
   }
   token('abc123')
   printContributedVariables(true)
   printPostContent(true)
   silentResponse(false)
   regexpFilterText("\$VARIABLE_FROM_POST")
   regexpFilterExpression("aRegExp")
  }
 }

 definition {
  cps {
   // Or just refer to a Jenkinsfile containing the pipeline
   script('''
 node {
 stage('Some Stage') {
 println "VARIABLE_FROM_POST: " + VARIABLE_FROM_POST
 }
 }
 ''')
   sandbox()
  }
 }
}
```

This part let's me config the first variable.

```
key("VARIABLE_FROM_POST")
value("\$.something")
```

However, if I add another code block and try to add another variable like this:

```
pipelineJob('Generic Job Example') {
 parameters {
  stringParam('VARIABLE_FROM_POST', '')
 }

 triggers {
  genericTrigger {
   genericVariables {
    genericVariable {
     key("VARIABLE_FROM_POST")
     value("\$.something")
     expressionType("JSONPath") //Optional, defaults to JSONPath
     regexpFilter("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
     defaultValue("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
    genericVariable {
     key("project")
     value("\$.repository.name")
     expressionType("JSONPath") //Optional, defaults to JSONPath
     regexpFilter("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
     defaultValue("") //Optional, defaults to empty string
    }
    }
   }
   genericRequestVariables {
    genericRequestVariable {
     key("requestParameterName")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
   }
   genericHeaderVariables {
    genericHeaderVariable {
     key("requestHeaderName")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
   }
   token('abc123')
   printContributedVariables(true)
   printPostContent(true)
   silentResponse(false)
   regexpFilterText("\$VARIABLE_FROM_POST")
   regexpFilterExpression("aRegExp")
  }
 }

 definition {
  cps {
   // Or just refer to a Jenkinsfile containing the pipeline
   script('''
 node {
 stage('Some Stage') {
 println "VARIABLE_FROM_POST: " + VARIABLE_FROM_POST
 }
 }
 ''')
   sandbox()
  }
 }
}
```

This results in job creation with only one variable, project as the variable name.

I tried other syntax manipulation and no luck. Is there link where it shows how these scripts can be created? I checkout the Jenkins Job DSL API [here](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/) and I could not find the answer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Do you use the latest version of all plugins and the latest Jenkins LTS release?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found this link useful: https://diycode.cc/projects/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin
I am using the generic webhooks plugin but don't have access to the violation to gitlab one in my organisation, so I used the declaritive jenkinsfile example in the link and came up with something like this, which worked:

```js
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string( name: 'action_type', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'action', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'packageid', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'toenvironment', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'totype', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'actionreturncode', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'actionccid', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'elementname', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'tosystem', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'tosubsystem', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'tostageID', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string( name: 'actionuserid', defaultValue: '', description: '')
    }
    triggers {
        GenericTrigger(
            genericVariables: [
                [key: 'action_type', value:'$.actiontype'],
                [key: 'action', value: '$.action'],
                [key: 'packageid', value: '$.packageid'],
                [key: 'toenvironment', value: '$.toenvironment'],
                [key: 'totype', value: '$.totype'],
                [key: 'actionreturncode', value: '$.actionreturncode'],
                [key: 'actionccid', value: '$.actionccid'],
                [key: 'elementname', value: '$.elementname'],
                [key: 'tosystem', value: '$.tosystem'],
                [key: 'tosubsystem', value: '$.tosubsystem'],
                [key: 'tostageID', value: '$.tostageID'],
                [key: 'actionuserid', value: '$.actionuserid']
            ],
            causeString: 'Tirggered on $action_type',                
            regexpFilterText: '$totype',
            regexpFilterExpression: 'COBOL'
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage ('initialise parms etc...') {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can prefer this link https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Violation+Comments+to+GitLab+Plugin

```
triggers {
  genericTrigger {
   genericVariables {
    genericVariable {
     key("MERGE_REQUEST_TO_URL")
     value("\$.object_attributes.target.git_http_url")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
    genericVariable {
     key("MERGE_REQUEST_FROM_URL")
     value("\$.object_attributes.source.git_http_url")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
    genericVariable {
     key("MERGE_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH")
     value("\$.object_attributes.target_branch")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
    genericVariable {
     key("MERGE_REQUEST_FROM_BRANCH")
     value("\$.object_attributes.source_branch")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
    genericVariable {
     key("PROJECT_ID")
     value("\$.object_attributes.target_project_id")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
    genericVariable {
     key("MERGE_REQUST_ID")
     value("\$.object_attributes.id")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
    genericVariable {
     key("MR_OBJECT_KIND")
     value("\$.object_kind")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
    genericVariable {
     key("MR_OLD_REV")
     value("\$.object_attributes.oldrev")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
    genericVariable {
     key("MR_ACTION")
     value("\$.object_attributes.action")
     expressionType("JSONPath")
     regexpFilter("")
    }
   }
```